# Style button when :active different from :hover

Tags: css, hover

I want to make a button that displays a background color when hovering and a button color without a background color when the button is down. Here is my current code:

```
.windowButton:hover {
    background-color:#1a82b8;
}
.windowButton:active #windowClose polygon {
    fill:#1a82b8;
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it turns the icon a color when `:active` but doesn't remove the background color set by `:hover`. How do I remove the background color?

Comment: Setting a new background property in :active?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set a new background color on `:hover` state

```
.windowButton:hover {
    background-color:#1a82b8;
}
.windowButton:active {
   fill:#1a82b8;
   background-color:#000000;/*You can put the color you want*/
}
```

Pseudo states inherit values. For consistency purposes, it is best to only declare the styles which you are changing in your pseudo state rules.

**Note:** `:hover` MUST come after `:link` and `:visited` (if they are present) in the CSS definition, in order to be effective!

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

I would guess, its cause on the first property you are using **background-color** and the second **fill**.

```
button:hover {
    background-color: red;
}
button:active {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[**jsFiddle working example** (1)](http://jsfiddle.net/Aa728/)

Comment: Background color is to color the div's background; fill is to color the svg icon inside the div.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the active state to be applied while the user is also hovering over the button, it's necessary for the `:hover` selector to come before the `:active` selector in the code.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active:

> Styles defined by the :active pseudo-class will be overridden by any
> subsequent link-related pseudo-class (:link, :hover, or :visited) that
> has at least equal specificity. To style links appropriately, put the
> :active rule after all other link-related rules, as defined by the
> LVHA-order: :link — :visited — :hover — :active.

While the accepted answer did mention that it's necessary to have `:active` come after `:link` and `:visited`, it doesn't say that it must also come after `:hover` (since in the example given in the question this was already the case). However this wasn't immediately clear to me, so I wanted to post this answer for anyone else who was stuck like I was because the `:hover` selector was coming after `:active`.

Also, I think the LVHA-order is a handy rule to keep in mind and relevant to this question.

Answer (score -1):

`button:hover{background-color: transparent;color: yellow;}

button:active {background: white;color: black;}`