# Can anyone tell help me make a proper animation for this button? (as in pressing)

Tags: html, css, animation, button

```css
.button {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Bradley Hand;
  color: purple;
  background: rgb(0, 255, 0);   /*Default settings for button*/
  border: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
.button:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 255, 125); /*Changes the buttons size, color,*/
  width: 120px;                 /*and font size*/
  height: 60px;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<button class = "button">Click me!</button>
```

I want it to look like you are actually pressing a button. Someone help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and look at this side on w3schools, they got some pretty good code on button animations. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_animate_buttons.asp

Comment: can you vote up my question plz

Comment: If you like my answer, you can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive

```
.button:active { /* your code here */}
```

I suggest you make it darker when clicked, maybe add a gradient inside so it looks recessed.

[Style button when :active different from :hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907052/style-button-when-active-different-from-hover)

Comment: Thanks! I will do that.

Comment: can you vote up my question plz